# How can I specify "split or move" logic for <C-W><C-L> and similar move commands?

Tags: vimrc, split

Is it possible to make `<C-W><C-L>` command to make split on the right, if it's the rightmost pane opened? Otherwise, it would behave like regular move. It's something like "conditional splitting" I would say.

**Example**:
I've got two panes opened, split vertically. Cursor is currently on the right pane. I press `<C-W><C-L>` and I create third pane and my cursor is moved there.

If I press `<C-W><C-L>` from the leftmost pane, nothing unusual happens, I just move to the already existing pane to the right.

P.S.: which are common bindings for splitting panes among Vim users?

Comment: As Dedowsdi mentions, Im fine with usual commands. I use either `<C-w><C-v/s>` if i want to split the same file (not often the case, but useful to work on two parts of the same file), or `:[v]split` to split to other files files.

Comment: [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble), thank you for sharing your experience. Maybe I'll discover the same for myself when I become experienced enough with Vim. But `:[v]split` will be handy for sure, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split and move if window doesn't change after `<c-w><c-*>`:

```
nnoremap <c-w><c-j> :call <sid>smart_split('j')<cr>
nnoremap <c-w><c-k> :call <sid>smart_split('k')<cr>
nnoremap <c-w><c-h> :call <sid>smart_split('h')<cr>
nnoremap <c-w><c-l> :call <sid>smart_split('l')<cr>

function! s:smart_split(cmd)
  " original window number
  let wn = winnr()

  " try to move to other window
  exec 'wincmd ' . a:cmd

  " do nothing if window changed
  if wn != winnr() | return | endif

  " otherwise split vertical or horizontal based on a:cmd
  exec 'wincmd ' . (a:cmd =~# '[lh]' ? 'v' : 's')

  " move to new window. You only need this 50% of time.
  exec 'wincmd ' . a:cmd
endfunction
```

I don't used this, i'm fine with default window splitting command binding.